# No se guardan los datos enviados en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy teniendo problemas para enviar los datos del formulario a la base de datos SQL. He probado que al enviar el formulario guarda los datos correctamente con : var_dump($sql):
`string(157) "INSERT INTO comentarios(id,nombre,comentario,fecha, califiacion) VALUES(NULL,'Alberto Garrido','Esto es un comentario para enviar','2021-09-19 10:09:08','4')"`.

Que estoy haciendo mal?
He buscado en Google y veo que los datos de conexión son correctos al igual que el envío del formulario teniendo en cuenta name="enviar". También he probado en el formulario `action="./insertar.php"` por si acaso hubiera algún error pero creo que lo correcto es poner: `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`  pero el resultado es igual, envía los datos como muestra la imagen adjunta pero no se reflejan en la base de datos.

PD: Los datos se envían correctamente, pero NO se guardan en la dase de datos MYSQL. Estoy trabajando desde localhost.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

````
<?php

require './functions/conexion.php';
$errors = array();

    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
        // Si existe el elemento enviar en POST
        $mi_nombre = $_POST['miNombre'];
        $mi_calificacion = $_POST['miCalificacion'];
        $mi_comentario = $_POST['miComentario'];
  

    if(!empty($mi_nombre) && !empty($mi_calificacion) && !empty($mi_comentario)){
        //No estan vacios los campos
        $mi_fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO comentarios(id,nombre,comentario,fecha, calificacion) VALUES(NULL,'$mi_nombre','$mi_comentario','$mi_fecha','$mi_calificacion')";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        var_dump($sql);
    }else{
        $errors[] = "Faltan campos";
    }

  }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/estilos.css">
    <title>Comentarios</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Sistema de comentario</h2>
        <div class="row">

        <div class="comentario">
            
        <div class="form">
            <form class="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
                <label class="fs-5 form-label" for="">Nombre:</label>
                <input class="fs-5 form-control" type="text" name="miNombre">
                <label class="fs-5 form-label" for="">Calificación:</label>
                <label class="fs-5 form-check-label" for=""> 1</label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="1" name="miCalificacion" id="">

                <label class="fs-5 form-check-label" for=""> 2</label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="2" name="miCalificacion" id="">

                <label class="fs-5 form-check-label" for=""> 3</label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="3" name="miCalificacion" id="">

                <label class="fs-5 form-check-label" for=""> 4</label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="4" name="miCalificacion" id="">

                <label class="fs-5 form-check-label" for=""> 5</label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="5" name="miCalificacion" id="" checked></br>

                <label class="fs-5 form-label" for="">Comentario:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="miComentario" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-2" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar">

            </form>
        </div>
       
        <?php
                    if(count($errors) > 0){
                        echo "<div class='badge bg-danger text-wrap p-2' style='width: 12rem;'>";
                        foreach ($errors as $key) {
                            echo  "<i class='bi bi-exclamation-lg'></i>" . $key . "</br> ";

                        }
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
            $mysqli->close();

            ?>
        </div>



        </div>
        <div class="btn-add">
        <a href="./index.php"><button class="btn btn-primary mt-2"><i class="bi bi-plus-square""> Regresar</i></button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

```
````

Comment: ¿Has comprobado la sentencia de insert directamente en MySQL? Estaría bien además que comprobaras si $result es false, si es así indica un  error $result en la operación.

Comment: Hola Juan, me devuelve bool(false) cuando envía los datos. Que puede ser?

Comment: Después de revisar insistentemente una y otra vez, encontré el fallo: ``` $sql = "INSERT INTO comentarios(id,nombre,comentario,fecha, califiacion) VALUES(NULL,'$mi_nombre','$mi_comentario','$mi_fecha','$mi_calificacion')";
```
Por: ```
$sql = "INSERT INTO comentarios(id,nombre,comentario,fecha, calificacion) VALUES(NULL,'$mi_nombre','$mi_comentario','$mi_fecha','$mi_calificacion')";
```

Answer (score 2):

Mas allá del hecho de que tu query no funciona debido al *typo* en el nombre de una columna (*que señalas en tu propia respuesta*), considera que tu script no te podrá avisar en realidad que ocurre mas allá de un *`bool(false)`* por que no has programado como administrar dichos problemas.

Entonces sugiero adaptes tu código para que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
.......................
.......................
$sql = "INSERT INTO comentarios(id,nombre,comentario,fecha, califiacion) VALUES(NULL,'$mi_nombre','$mi_comentario','$mi_fecha','$mi_calificacion')";
$resultadoConsulta = $mysqli->query($sql);

if (!$resultadoConsulta) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
.......................
.......................
```

A partir de este punto y con fines de **depuración**, visualizarás un mensaje de error mas descriptivo como el siguiente (**para este caso en concreto**):

> Unknown column 'califiacion' in 'field list'

Por otro lado y como comentario extra, considera que si el id de tu columna tiene un valor auto incremental entonces no hace falta invocar a dicha columna y tampoco agregarle el valor `NULL` en la definición del `INSERT`.

Finalmente sugiero repases [este apartado de la doc. de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php#refsect1-mysqli.error-examples)

Comment: En verdad puedes comprobar que mis conocimiento en PHP son escasos. Seguiré repasando, probando y aprendiendo de gente como usted. gracias BetaM por tu tiempo quiere decir mucho de ti.

Comment: @AlbertoGarrido la forma de agradecer es marcando esta respuesta como aceptada si la misma sirve para resolver tu problema, y votándola positivamente (pulsando sobre la flecha gris que apunta hacia arriba en la parte izquierda).

Comment: Hola Cedano, como no voy a votar el apoyo de BetaM? Lo que ocurre es  que: ` Los votos emitidos por quienes tienen menos de 15 de reputación se registran, pero no cambian la puntuación que se muestra públicamente.` gracias por estar atento. saludos

Comment: @AlbertoGarrido yo, como moderador, no se de que eestas hablando y donde leiste eso... los votos que emitis, se contabilizan siempre. Es mas, si esta respuesta soluciono tu problema, deberias aceptarla...

Comment: Por favor usted puede informarse antes aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: Aquí tiene la prueba gráfica, saludos: https://i.postimg.cc/8CgDP74z/Captura32.png